# A circuit to detect AC and DC voltage from a source

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, ac, voltage-regulator, capacitance

I am looking for a circuit that determines whether the input signal is AC or DC.

For example, if the AC voltage is connected, the red LED will turn on, and if the DC voltage is connected, the green LED will turn on.

Comment: See if the solution to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/690270/73158 is of any help.

Comment: Do you know what voltage the AC or DC signal is likely to be?

Comment: @Transistor I don't want it to be manual. I want it to switch automatically

Comment: @SimonB No i want different

Comment: "*I don't want it to be manual. I want it to switch automatically.*" The LEDs do that. The switch is to change the supply, not the indicators. Read it again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you at least give us a clue as to what voltage range you're expecting?  Something that will work with a 100mV signal will probably go bang if you feed it 230V AC, unless you have a much more clever design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You could connect two LEDs with a resistor in series as shown in the picture.
If your voltage is AC, both LEDs will be on. If it's DC, only one will be on.

Assuming you know the orientation of your DC Voltage you can connect the positve end with IN1 and use a green LED as D2 to achieve your desired colorcoding.